# renewcommand error mathbm

Tags: macros

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbm{#1}}
```

Then I write

```
\[\vec{a}\]
```

which yields an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\vec #1->\mathbm 
                 {#1}
l.564 \[\vec{a}
               \]
?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're interested in printing **boldface** mathematics, use `\mathbf{...}` instead:

```
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}%
```

Alternatively, you need to use

```
\usepackage{bm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bm
...
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}% Bold math
```

This shows the difference:

[image: Difference between bm and mathbf]